# Bulk Import of Data File - Steps

Tags: sql, sql-server

"The database performs regular FULL and LOG backups. The database uses the FULL RECOVERY model.
You plan to perform a bulk import of a large text file.
You need to ensure:
a) Database transaction log is minimally affected.
b) Database is online and user transactions are recoverable. All transactions are fully recoverable prior to the import.
What THREE actions would you perform and in what order?"

Actions:
i Perform Database LOG backup
ii Perform a fULL database backup
iii Configure database to use FULL recovery model
iv Execute BCP tool
v Configure database to use BULK-LOGGED recovery model

My answer would be 
1 FULL db backup
2 Configure to use BULK-LOGGED
3 Execute BCP

Would this be correct? Or should a LOG backup be run instead?

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of SQL Server? I have a feeling it's more suitable to DBA's.

Comment: Both FULL and LOG backups would be appropriate, but neither of them are required for BULK LOGGED to work. That question is confusing. What would "user transactions are recoverable" even mean? Where is that quiz question from?